# croak vs croaks vs croaking

Tags: nouns

I want to write:

> Do you remember the pond full of frog croaking at night?

Or should it be

> Do you remember the pond full of frogs croaking at night?

Or

> Do you remember the pond of frog croaking at night?

or

> Do you remember the pond of frog croaks at night?

Or

> Do you remember the pond of frog croak at night?

You get what I'm trying to say.  What's the best, grammatically correct,
succinct way to express this?  I'm trying to convey a memory of a pond which had many frogs who croaked ferociously at night. There must be a better way (better than the alternatives) to express this idea with elegance and economy? Imagine Hemingway sitting at his typewriter with the same idea swirling in his head...

The emphasis is the pond. Perhaps it's better to write: Do you remember the pond, where frogs croaked raucously at night?

Is "croak" countable?  So plural of "croak" would be "croaks"?

Comment: What in the world do you mean by "this" in "express this"? The only one of these that is ungrammatical is the last one, and it may be that "Frog Croak" is a local name for something. The others don't mean the same thing, though they can all refer to the same memory. There is almost never just **one** "best, grammatically correct, succinct way" to express anything, let alone half a dozen similar things.

Comment: ... I'll add 'a pond of frog croaks' to my list of occasional collective nouns.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I'm trying to convey a memory of a pond which had many frogs who croaked ferociously at night.  There must be a better way (better than the alternatives) to express this idea with elegance and economy?  Imagine Hemingway sitting at his typewriter with the same idea swirling in his head...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - That reminds me, I need to pick up a pound of frog croaks on my way home tonight.

Comment: Do you want to remind the person of the night, filled with the sound of croaking frogs from the pond? Or the pond, where the frogs croaked raucously at night?

Comment: Decide what you want to call it and do so. BTW, Hemingway used pencil and notebook.  It took Hemingway a long long time to figure out how to write the way he did. He started out being as prolix and clueless as anybody else.

Comment: Advice on literary style is toadally off-topic.

Comment: _"Do you remember that night? The romantic, sinuous, shades of dusk; the magical pond; the clamorous, urgent croaking of the frogs?" _"Nope."

Comment: @KristinaLopez I like your version.  The emphasis is the pond.  Perhaps it's better to write: Do you remember the pond, where frogs croaked raucously at night?  (note I drop "the" from "frogs")

Comment: Even the last option might be okay if you change _pond_ to _pound_, as in "Do you remember the pound of frog croak at night?"

Answer (score 0):

Do you remember the pond, with sound of frogs croaking in the night?